# Travelling to Estonia via Norway, will my passport be stamped into Schengen in Oslo?

Tags: schengen, norway, estonia

I'm flying to Tallinn, Estonia via Oslo with Norwegian.
I need to enter Estonia on my Estonian visa, and thus cannot be stamped into Schengen beforehand as this will cause complications.
If I'm transiting through Oslo for 1hr 30mins, will my passport be stamped?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be deleted instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a [non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content](/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing) under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)?

Answer (score 15):

> I need to enter Estonia on my Estonian visa,

You *will* be entering Estonia on your Estonian visa.

> and thus cannot be stamped into Schengen beforehand as this will cause complications.

Why not?  What complications will it cause?

The stamp that you get from Norway will look just like the stamp you'd get from Estonia, except that it will show that you entered the Schengen area in Oslo instead of through an Estonian border station, and it will bear an "N" for Norway instead of an "EST" for Estonia.

As Thomas Cruise suggests in [his answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/174749/19400), requiring people to enter the Schengen area through the country that issued the visa makes no sense, and in fact there are several points where the Schengen regulations specifically contemplate people entering the area through a country other than the one issuing the visa or even require it.

This is why I asked for clarification of the complications you anticipate.  If you have some source suggesting that you need a passport stamp *from Estonia,* perhaps we can help identify whether you have misinterpreted the source or whether it's simply incorrect.

> If I'm transiting through Oslo for 1hr 30mins, will my passport be stamped?

Yes it will.  There is no way to avoid this other than to change your ticket so as to fly to Estonia from an airport outside the Schengen area.

Comment: Thanks. How can I be simultaneously stamped into Schengen and on an Estonian visa? Would I then be stamped out of Schengen in Estonia?

Comment: @Bob Estonia is part of the Schengen area.  You cannot be stamped out of Schengen and then remain in the Schengen area, so you cannot be stamped out of Schengen and then remain in Estonia.  Similarly, you can "be simultaneously stamped into Schengen and on an Estonian visa" for the same reason: because Estonia is part of the Schengen area.

Comment: @Bob What has made you think that being stamped into the Schengen area and being in Estonia on a visa would be a problem? Being stamped into Schengen gives you the right to travel and remain in the Schengen area for a certain period of time; being in Estonia on a visa gives you the right to travel and remain in Estonia (a subsection of the Schengen area) for a certain period of time. There’s nothing contradictory about those two rights.

Answer (score 14):

Schengen area is a single border control area. You pass through passport control at the first port of landing in the Schengen area and last port of departure. You don't need to land in Estonia on an Estonia visa and it doesn't cause any complications.

Schengen has been in existance for decades and countless people travel in and out everyday. Not all 26 Schengen countries have wide connectivity. A significant percent of people use larger airlines like KLM, Air France, Lufthansa etc to enter the Schengen area and thus pass through immigration in the Netherlands, France, Germany, etc. regardless of where visas or residence permits were issued from.

It is a non-issue.

Comment: Exactly. There won't even be a passport check on arrival to Tallinn, as it's a "domestic" flight.